# Jquery class click event calls multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append the image with class (menuSelector) in jquery and then writing some functionality on the click of the class.

```
$("<div>").addClass("node").append($("<img>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" }))
                                 .data("tree-node", nodeCount)
                                 .append($nodeContent);

$('.menuSelector').live("click",function (event) {
     alert('I am clicked');
    });
```

Now the problem is the class click event calls in loop for every image item it found.

HTML:

```
<div class="node" style="cursor: n-resize;">
<img src="/GroupTree/styles/pointer.gif" class="menuSelector">Group 1</div>

<div class="node" style="cursor: n-resize;">
<img src="/GroupTree/styles/pointer.gif" class="menuSelector">Group 2</div>
```

I think, If I closed the image tag, may be my problem would solve but Its not closing :(

I tried:

```
.append($("<img/>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" }))
and
.append($("<img/>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" },"</img>"))
and
.append($("<img/>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" })).append($("</img>"))
```

But they didn't work.

Comment: You're adding the click handler inside the loop, and it applies to every image. Move the click handler outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I was adding click handler inside the loop. Moving the click handler solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this`
something like that:

```
$('.menuSelector').on("click",function (event) {
    console.log(this); // this - add some action for this
    $(this).hide(); // for test ))
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append($("<img/>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" }))` is correct.

I wager that your problem is somehow connect to the use of `$.fn.live`.  Try using `$.fn.bind` or if that doesn't work, try delegating from the parent `<div>` using `$.fn.delegate`.

You may also have to post more code to make your intention clearer if the previous solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The line

$('.menuSelector').live("click",function (event) {
     alert('I am clicked');
    });

register the event to every element with menuSelector class in every iteration !

try to do

```
var img = $("<div>").addClass("node").append($("<img>", { src: menuImg, class: "menuSelector" }))
img.live("click",function (event) {
     alert('I am clicked');
    });
img.data("tree-node", nodeCount).append($nodeContent)
```

This will add the callback only for the current image

By the way, .live is deprecated and was removed - see http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

This one simple line helped in my case:

event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Just put it right after your function call

https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/